# Matlab Issue with functions

Tags: matlab

So, i have been doing this work with matlab and every time i try to get the answer a new problem pops up. The one that repeats the most on the prompt is

```
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.
```

The work is about deriving with matlab, i have to derive a function with two diferent derivation methods and i have to get that table. Thanks a lot to everyone that trys to answer im very lost with this subject.

```
clc,clear;
h=1;
x=1.2;

derivada1=derivada_1(x,h);
derivada2=derivada_2(x,h);

for i=0:1:10
    fprintf('%.10f %.10f %.10f\n',h*(10.^(-i)),derivada1,derivada2);
end
```

The function i have to derive is

```
    function [ fx ] = funcion( x )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    fx=x.^3-3*x.^2-x+3;

end
```

Method1

```
    function [ dfx1 ] = derivada_1( x,h )
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    fx=feval(funcion,x);
    fh2=feval(fx,x+h);
    fh3=feval(fx,x-h);
    dfx1=(fh2-fh3)/(2*h);

end
```

Method 2

```
    function [ dfx2 ] = derivada_2( x,h )
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    fx=feval(funcion,x);
    fh1=feval(fx,x+2*h);
    fh2=feval(fx,x+h);
    fh3=feval(fx,x-h);
    fh4=feval(fx,x-2*h);
    dfx2=(-fh1+8*fh2-8*fh3+fh4)/(12*h);

end
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a6kT.png)

[Table of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQgqq.png)

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to do? You evaluate the function with the input argument x, returning a double and then you want to evaluate it again?

Comment: The code is supposed to derive the function with the two methods in the point x=1.2. Not sure about it, but what i think it does is, i have a function called 'funcion', but is only locally defined so i have to defined again in the other functions in order to work, if i dont i get the same error saying that fx is not defined

Comment: `function [ fx ] = funcion( x )` - seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really over-complicated it using `feval`, it's that simple:

```
function [ dfx1 ] = derivada_1(x,h )
    fh2=funcion(x+h);
    fh3=funcion(x-h);
    dfx1=(fh2-fh3)/(2*h);
end
```

The problem with your original code was you didn't use function handles. `feval(funcion,x)` evaluates `funcion` and passes the returned values to feval, but `funcion` requires input arguments. Instead it should be something like `feval(@funcion,x)` passing a function handle (aka function pointer in other programming languages).

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :)